# Байт режима адресации Mod r/m

Tags: ассемблер, машинный-код

```
83 F8 09             cmp eax, 9
```

Байт `modr/m` `11 111 000`

Почему в поле reg "111"? Что означает?

Comment: Теперь стало понятно, спасибо

Comment: Внезапно, нашел аналогичный вопрос, на который сам же когда-то отвечал